# Using GitHub in a classroom

Tags: github, rstudio

I'm going to be teaching a data journalism class next year to students with fairly weak coding and computer skills. I'm prepared to do the work necessary to guide them through using R to learn how to scrape data, make plots and maps and such.

However, I am thinking about how to enable them to work in groups.

Obviously GitHub is the place for collaborative work on projects, but, wow, it has a learning curve.

I am wondering if it would be possible for me to set up one repo for the entire class and then somehow have each group in the class have their own branches for their own projects so that I could kind of oversee the merges as they work on their projects.

I can see the merits of GitHub for this, but I am trying to make it as simple as possible.

Please note, I see that GitHub Classroom is a thing, but that really seems to facilitate grading and marking for large classes. That's not really what I need.

Comment: I'm just thinking this through. I'm tempted to set up one repository for each group, then have the students start an RStudio project on their harddrive by cloning their group's repo. 
Each class, i could have student's create their own branch to work on projects, then I could merge the good from each branch to create a working master copy that each member could then pull.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest having each student create a fork of your base repository so that they can do work on their own copy of your code. This way, they'll each have their own workspace that they can contribute to alone. You could even have them create a new fork for each group collaboration.

[See the documentation here for information on forking repositories.](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)

Comment: You think forking would be better than branching? I know there is a difference, but I'm not sure how well.

Comment: Forking repositories will allow each student to see an entire copy of their repo under their own Github space, whereas branches may lead to confusion as a student could push their code update to someone else's branch by mistake. You'll only have to protect the main repository against pushes if you go with a forking strategy, whereas you'd need to protect each branch if you go with a branch per student (https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-protected-branches/)